# Aligning Children List Items to Parent in Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, menu

I'm attempting to build a dropdown menu similar to [this site](https://www.simple.com/).

How do I:

1. Align the children list items under main nav list item?
2. Display all children list items no matter which main nav list item is hovered over?

Below are some code snippets. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/EBrodo?editors=1111) for full code.

```css
.nav > li > a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      z-index: 510;
      height: 54px;
      padding: 0 50px;
      line-height: 54px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="main-nav">
          <ul className="nav">
            <li>
              <a>Products</a>
    
              <div className="subnav-block">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a>Product A</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a>Product B</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
```

Comment: To line up your child list elements you need to remove padding from your `a` elements within your list and then reduce the padding on the entire dropdown. This needs to be set as a pixel amount, not a percentage because your nav header is a pixel amount. Otherwise they will skew based on screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aligning the children, you can make sure the children have the same padding/width as the parent.

```
.nav > li > a {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav .subnav-block li a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

For showing all of the children on hover, simply use :hover on the parent instead of the child:

```
.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I did some more changes, see the pen for details.

https://codepen.io/davidtorresdesign/pen/agXGPY

Comment: nicely done! Setting position to 'static' on .subnav-block finished this off. I was tinkering with javaScript to achieve this but looks like I don't have to. thanks!

Comment: @ davidtorresdesign since we set a width of 200px, the dropdown bar doesn't extend 100% of the screen. Is there a way to also do this and keep the items aligned?

Comment: @EricNguyen, in order to do that the structure needs to change.  Namely, the subnav-block needs to be outside of the nav ul element, see this pen for a solution https://codepen.io/davidtorresdesign/pen/dBaQBV